# Conflicts with multiple queries Doctrine (Symfony 2 website)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Good afternoon,

I have an important issue in my website and I really don't succeed to resolve it.

My website is a game where the users do mission and get some rewards after completing it. It is developped with Symfony 2.8 and doctrine 2.4

In my dev environment, I've made many tests and it seems to work properly, but some of my users are complaining that sometimes (not always), they don't get the rewards after ending the missions.

The fact is I have around 1000 concurrent users at the same time and I think there might be some conflicts in the different queries.

Also, I've a listener that can update the user in certain conditions, so is that possible that the flush in the listener erase the flush called after in the controller?

Of course I can send any code if needed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: share your code, what do you mean by conflicts? Is there any error you got?

Comment: PHP requests are excuted totally seperate from each other. So a conflict could only really happen on the database level or any other component of your system outside of PHP. Multiple flush's in one request usually should not be a problem by itself. Did you check your log files for errors? Can you share some relevant code?